# Android: Behaviour of Camera Activity on Orientation

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-camera

Camera Activity in my project contains three main components Camera, View pager and Navigation Drawer. Upon orientation changes, I do not want to stop camera preview but rotate view pager and navigation drawer behaviour according to orientation of the device.

How can I manage only certain view groups when device orientation changes. For example, Samsung Camera is rotating view pager and few icons when device orientation changes without stopping preview **even if orientation of device is locked (Screenshots are attached to the question)**

I looked into different solutions:

1. Add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to manifest and implement `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`.
2. Keep Activity portrait and rotate the views based on the Orientation Listener.

I want to know proper approach to implement but not the entire code. Any technical approach will be appreciated.

Any help is appreciated here.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure that you can actually do this.  The android activity lifecycle states pretty clearly that the activity is destroyed and recreated on an orientation change.  The "right" thing to do is just save your state and restore it.

Comment: You're on the right way. By specifying `configChanges` flags you are telling the framework, that you are going to handle configuration changes on your own, otherwise system will take care of doing that for you (i.e. it will destroy activity, create new one with new configuration, e.g. landscape, thus reading resources from `land` etc.). As soon as a configuration change happens (see `onConfigurationChange`) - apply necessary changes to your `ViewPager` laying out it correctly.

Comment: @alzee: If you see Google Camera, it does the same way. Camera preview remains live and navigation drawer and icons gets rotated.

Comment: The built in camera does this by inhibiting the automatic orientation change and instead rotating and moving all of it's controls around itself.  You can certainly do that, but it's a lot of work.